# Simplifing a Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean, simplification

Please see my image for the question - it includes a work-through of my equation, and I'd like some clarification on some points.

[image: Boolean Simplification]

Comment: 1) What have you tried so far? 2) Please don't post images when actual text could be used.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response.  I've completed the equations, but I'm after some clarification, so my worked example in the iage was the only way I could do this in a clear way.